# Error in AndroidManifest.xml While Implementing FragmentScenario in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, gradle

While implementing FragmentScenario for testing user interface interactions with Fragment layouts in Android Studio, I added the line debugImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:${fragment_version}" to the dependencies in the build.gradle(Module.app) file. However, during the build process, I encountered a potential conflict related to the Activity's Theme, leading to a build error. Dose anyone come up with any idea solving following error message ?

● Error Message

```
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
C:\Android_Project\application\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:41:13-49 Error:
    Attribute activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$BootstrapActivity@theme value=(@android:style/Theme) from [com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.0] AndroidManifest.xml:41:13-49
    is also present at [androidx.test:core:1.5.0] AndroidManifest.xml:30:13-56 value=(@style/WhiteBackgroundTheme).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to <activity> element at AndroidManifest.xml to override.
C:\Android_Project\application\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:49:13-49 Error:
    Attribute activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyActivity@theme value=(@android:style/Theme) from [com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.0] AndroidManifest.xml:49:13-49
    is also present at [androidx.test:core:1.5.0] AndroidManifest.xml:38:13-56 value=(@style/WhiteBackgroundTheme).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to <activity> element at AndroidManifest.xml to override.
C:\Android_Project\application\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:57:13-56 Error:
    Attribute activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyFloatingActivity@theme value=(@android:style/Theme.Dialog) from [com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.0] AndroidManifest.xml:57:13-56
    is also present at [androidx.test:core:1.5.0] AndroidManifest.xml:46:13-62 value=(@style/WhiteBackgroundDialogTheme).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to <activity> element at AndroidManifest.xml to override.
```

Moreover following is the code for AndroidManifest.xml and build.gradle(Module.app):

● build.gradle(Module.app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.google.devtools.ksp'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

android {
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "{package_name}"
        minSdk 27
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_18
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_18
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '18'
    }


    testOptions.unitTests {
        includeAndroidResources = true
        returnDefaultValues = true
    }


    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }

    namespace '{package_name}'
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        buildConfig true
    }
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes true
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0"

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.2'

    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.6'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.6'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.4.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:21.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:22.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.10.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:20.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx:23.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions-ktx:20.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:21.5.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:16.2.0'

    implementation 'com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'

    implementation 'com.github.krokyze:ucropnedit:2.2.8'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:3.0.1'

    implementation 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.22'
    implementation 'com.iceteck.silicompressorr:silicompressor:2.2.4'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.3"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.3"

    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-core:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-video:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-view:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.3.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.19.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.19.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.19.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.19.1'

    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:32.1.3-jre'

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.1"
    ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.1"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.6.1"

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:3.3.0'

    implementation 'com.github.MikeOrtiz:TouchImageView:3.2.1'

    implementation 'io.github.nikartm:image-support:2.0.0'

    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.13.25'

    implementation 'com.github.shuhart:stepview:1.5.1'

    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:2.1.6'

    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:20.34.4'

    implementation 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:3.0.0-RC3'

    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.50'
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.50'

    debugImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.6.2"
    implementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.5.1"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.5'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    testImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.11.1'
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.7.3"

    testImplementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.50"
    kaptTest "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.50"

    androidTestImplementation "junit:junit:4.13.2"
    androidTestImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.7.3"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.2.0"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:5.8.0'
    androidTestImplementation "com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:2.28.3"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.5.1"

    androidTestImplementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.50"
    kaptAndroidTest "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.50"

}
```

● AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

    <application
        android:name=".ApplicationName"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.App"
        tools:targetApi="34">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_like" /> 
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/pale_orange" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.share.selectresource.SelectResourceActivity"
            android:exported="false"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="nosensor">

            <intent-filter android:label="home_link"
                android:autoVerify="true">

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="www.application.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/home" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.login.LoginActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="nosensor">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.share.takephotoandvideo.TakePhotoAndVideoActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.App.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.selectresource.SelectResourceActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.identificationphoto.IdentificationPhotoActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="nosensor" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.canhub.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />

        <service
            android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken"
            android:value="@string/facebook_client_token" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled"
            android:value="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

As the error message indicates, I tried implementing tools:replace="android:theme" in each  tag of the AndroidManifest.xml file, but the following error occurred.

```
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
C:\Android_Project\application\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:84:9-88:44 Error:
    tools:replace specified at line:84 for attribute android:theme, but no new value specified
C:\Android_Project\application\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:89:9-93:44 Error:
    tools:replace specified at line:89 for attribute android:theme, but no new value specified
C:\Android_Project\application\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    Validation failed, exiting
```

And also, I tried to inplementing tools:node="replace" and tools:replace="android:theme" in  tag on the AndroidManifest.xml file, then upper build error disapeared but if I run it, I get various external library initialization errors in Activity.

Answer (score 0):

I have reviewed your error carefully. I suggest you edit the below lines as I edit in your Android Manifest file & then try to re-run the project.

---

- AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<!--edit the below registered activity like this-->
<activity
    android:name="com.canhub.cropper.CropImageActivity"
    tools:replace="android:theme"
    android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
```

> As the above error which you have mentioned is pointing to this activity's theme & suggesting to add the `tools:replace="android:theme"`
>
> ```
> C:\Android_Project\application\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:41:13-49 Error:
>    Attribute >activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$BootstrapActivity@them>e value=(@android:style/Theme) from [com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.0] >AndroidManifest.xml:41:13-49 
>    is also present at [androidx.test:core:1.5.0] AndroidManifest.xml:30:13-56 value=(@style/WhiteBackgroundTheme).
>    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to <activity> element at >AndroidManifest.xml to override.
> ```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to respond to my question. Since then, I have tried various methods to solve this issue on my own.And I reffered to the GitHub page of Crop Image Activity again, noticed that this "com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.0" seems to cause the probrems, and resolved the error by updating to  "com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0". Thereby In the testing, FragmentScenario now work effectively.

Comment: Yes, that's true.